# my ok button is not working...giving error while running app..whenever i m pressing an ok button it says force closes..in android

Tags: android

below are my code for "ok" button...whenever i m pressing my button named as "ok"....it is not performing any task either it hangs or gives error force closes...the code is very simple it just have to display the particular message as soon as i press the ok button as desired ......it is happening first time..so don't know how to solve this error

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      choice=0;
      ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      display=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
      view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
      view1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        name=display.getText().toString();
        choice=Integer.parseInt(name);
            while(choice>=50 && choice<=74)
            {
                if(choice==64||choice==65||choice==67) {
                    view1.setText("Please put the correct input as the Error no:64,65 & 67 does                   not fall under any category of error");
                }
                if(choice==50) {
                    view1.setText("DECLINED ATM AND POS NOT TICKED IN CBS OPTION CH021");
                }
                 if(choice==51) {
                    view1.setText("EXPIRED CARD");
                 }
                 if(choice==52)
                 {
                     view1.setText("INVALID CARD(WRONG 16 DIGIT CARD NUMBER PUNCHED)\\nIN   CMS01/CARD DETAILS NOT FOUND IN SWITCH DATA BASE AND NON PERSONALIZED CARD AUTHORISED AFTER 1 MONTH IN CMS01");
                }
                if((choice>=53&&choice<=63) || choice==68)
                {
                    view.setText("ERROR FALLS UNDER THE NON-TECHNICAL CATEGORY");
                    if(choice==53)
                    {
                    view1.setText("INVALID PIN");
                    }
                    if(choice==54)
                    {view1.setText("DATABASE PROBLEM (PBF NOT RECEIVED FOR THE A/C AND TXN TRIED IN OFF LINE)");

                    }
                    if(choice==55)
                    {
                        view1.setText("INELIGIBLE TRANSACTION (DECLINED FOR OTHER BANK CARD HOLDERS)");
                    }
                    if(choice==56)
                    {
                        view1.setText("INELIGIBLE ACCOUNT (SB A/C LINKED BUT CUSTOMER SELECTING CURRENT A/C IN ATM)");
                    }
                    if(choice==57)
                    {
                        view1.setText("TRANSACTION NOT SUPPORTED (CUSTOMER TRYING FOR CASH DEPOSIT, PRESENTLY NOT AVAILABLE)");
                    }
                    if(choice==58)
                    {
                        view1.setText("INSUFFICIENT FUNDS NO AMOUNT 3/ INSUFFICIENT FUNDS WITH AMOUNT 3");
                    }
                    if(choice==59)
                    {
                        view1.setText("INSUFFICIENT FUNDS NO AMOUNT 3/ INSUFFICIENT FUNDS WITH AMOUNT 3");
                    }
                    if(choice==60)
                    {
                        view1.setText("USES LIMIT EXCEEDED (FOR OTHER BANK CUSTOMERS FORM RESPECTIVE SWITCH)");
                    }
                    if(choice==61)
                    {
                        view1.setText("WITHDRAWAL LIMIT WOULD BE EXCEEDED (25000 ALREADY WITH DRAWN NEXT TRANSACTION TRYING FOR 7000)");

                    }
                    if(choice==62)
                    {
                        view1.setText("PIN TRIES EXCEEDED (ALREADY WRONGLY PUNCHED 3 TIMES)");

                    }
                    if(choice==63)
                    {
                        view1.setText("WITHDRAWAL LIMIT ALREADY REACHED( AFTER WITH DRAWING 25000 IF TRIED IT GIVES ERROR 61 SECOND TIME ONWARDS GIVE 63)");

                    }
                    if(choice==68)
                    {
                        view1.setText("EXTERNAL DECLINE(MEMO IN A/C OR SAME CARD LINKED TO 2 CUST DS OD A/C EXPIRED ETC)");

                    }
                }

                if((choice>=70&&choice<=74)|| choice==66) {
                    view.setText("ERROR FALLS UNDER TECHNICAL CATEGORY");
                 if(choice==70) {
                 view1.setText("SYSTEM ERROR (A/C MISMATCH BETWEEN CBS AND SWITCH)");
                 }
                    if(choice==71) {
                        view1.setText("CONTACT CARD ISSUER (NEW USER USED IN OFFLINE MODE)");
                    }
                    if(choice==72) {
                        view1.setText("DESTINATION NOT AVAILABLE /Mostly for other bank cards");
                    }
                    if(choice==73) {
                        view1.setText("ROUTING LOOK UP PROBLEM /Mostly for other bank cards");
                    }
                    if(choice==74) {
                        view1.setText("MESSAGE EDIT ERROR /ATM NOT READING THE DATA CORRECTLY SINCE MAGNETIC STRIP MAY BE DAMAGED");
                    }
                    if(choice==66) {
                        view1.setText("STATEMENT INFORMATION NOT AVAILABLE ( WHEN CBS IS OFF LINE MINI STATEMENT DOES NOT COME)");
                    }





                }


            }
        }
      });
```

Comment: post your logcat then...

Comment: remove `while(choice>=50 && choice<=74)`

Comment: Anybody else scared by the fact that this void looks like BANK CARD processing? Uhhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

```
while(choice>=50 && choice<=74)
```

Its an infinite loop. What you intend seems this:

```
if(choice>=50 && choice<=74)
```

Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop, choice never changes

```
while(choice>=50 && choice<=74)
```

Comment: oh..yup ..that was the only error...thanks a lot bro....next time i m going to use the comment....